# Google Analytics dashboard won't show "search query" data even when linked to Search Console

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, keywords, not-provided

My website's Google Analytics account is linked with Google Search Console. I see all search console data in the "Acquisition" report.

When I create a custom dashboard and make widgets for getting "search queries", there is no data.  Why would the dashboard not have that data?